# PyQt issue with resizing and repainting of QGraphicsRectItem

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsrectitem

I'm trying to create a resizable QGraphicsRectItem with an option to choose different draw styles.

If I create a simple rect with a resize feature only, then it works as expected:

```
class Rectangle(QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        super(Rectangle, self).__init__(0, 0, w, h)
        self.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, 2))
        self.setFlags(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable
            | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable
            | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable
            | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges
            | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsScenePositionChanges)
        self.setPos(QtCore.QPointF(x, y))

        self.rect = rect = QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 200, 200)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.rect.adjusted(-10, -10, 10, 10)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            super(Rectangle, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
        if event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            self.rect = QtCore.QRectF(QtCore.QPoint(), event.pos()).normalized()
            self.prepareGeometryChange()
            self.setRect(self.rect)
```

---

When i try to modify it to change pen styles and color if active, it becomes unselectable and unfocusable. More than that, the bounding rect disappears unexpectedly. Here's a modified version:

```
class Rectangle(QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, position, scene, style=QtCore.Qt.SolidLine,
                 rect=None, matrix=QtGui.QMatrix()):
        super(Rectangle, self).__init__()

        # self.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, 2))
        self.setFlags(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable
                      | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable
                      | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable
                      | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges
                      | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsScenePositionChanges)

        if rect is None:
            rect = QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 200, 200)

        self.size = QtCore.QPointF(200, 200)
        self.rect = rect
        self.style = style
        self.setPos(position)
        self.setMatrix(matrix)

        scene.clearSelection()
        scene.addItem(self)
        self.setSelected(True)
        self.setFocus()
        global RAW
        RAW = True

        self.pen = QtGui.QPen(self.style)
        self.pen.setColor(QtCore.Qt.black)
        self.pen.setWidth(1)

    def parentWidget(self):
        return self.scene().views()[0]

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.rect.adjusted(-10, -10, 10, 10)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected:
            self.pen.setColor(QtCore.Qt.blue)

        painter.setPen(self.pen)
        painter.drawRect(self.rect)

    def itemChange(self, change, variant):
        if change != QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSelectedChange:
            global RAW
            RAW = True
        return QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.itemChange(self, change, variant)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        wrapped = []
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.parentWidget())
        for text, param in (("&Solid", QtCore.Qt.SolidLine),
                            ("&Dashed", QtCore.Qt.DashLine),
                            ("D&otted", QtCore.Qt.DotLine),
                            ("D&ashDotted", QtCore.Qt.DashDotLine),
                            ("DashDo&tDotten", QtCore.Qt.DashDotDotLine)):
            wrapper = functools.partial(self.setStyle, param)
            wrapped.append(wrapper)
            menu.addAction(text, wrapper)
        menu.exec_(event.screenPos())

    def setStyle(self, style):
        #self.prepareGeometryChange()
        self.style = style
        self.update()
        global RAW
        RAW = True

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            super(Rectangle, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
        if event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton:
            if self.isSelected():
                self.rect = QtCore.QRectF(QtCore.QPoint(), event.pos()).normalized()
                self.prepareGeometryChange()
                self.setRect(self.rect)

            global RAW
            RAW = True
```

I guess that the main problem lays in reimplemented *paint()* function but I still haven't come up with any idea ***where*** exactly...

Could anyone explain what am I doing wrong?
Where's a mistake and how to make this thing work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have the middle button on my touchpad so I have implemented the logic with the right button but I have given a small edge of 10px where you can change the size of the rectangle.

To change the style you just have to change the QPen of the QGraphicsItem.

```
import functools
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Rectangle(QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        super(Rectangle, self).__init__(0, 0, w, h)
        self.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, 2))
        self.setFlags(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable
            | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable
            | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable
            | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges
            | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsScenePositionChanges)
        self.setPos(QtCore.QPointF(x, y))

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            super(Rectangle, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
        if event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            rect = QtCore.QRectF(QtCore.QPoint(), event.pos()).normalized()
            self.prepareGeometryChange()
            self.setRect(rect)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        super(Rectangle, self).contextMenuEvent(event)
        delta = 10
        r = self.boundingRect()
        r.adjust(delta, delta, -delta, -delta)
        if not r.contains(event.pos()):
            return
        self.setSelected(True)
        wrapped = []
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.parentWidget())
        for text, param in (("&Solid", QtCore.Qt.SolidLine),
                            ("&Dashed", QtCore.Qt.DashLine),
                            ("D&otted", QtCore.Qt.DotLine),
                            ("D&ashDotted", QtCore.Qt.DashDotLine),
                            ("DashDo&tDotten", QtCore.Qt.DashDotDotLine)):
            wrapper = functools.partial(self.setStyle, param)
            wrapped.append(wrapper)
            menu.addAction(text, wrapper)
        menu.exec_(event.screenPos())

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setPen(self.pen())
        painter.setBrush(self.brush())
        if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected:
            pen = self.pen()
            pen.setColor(QtCore.Qt.blue)
            painter.setPen(pen)
            painter.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.NoBrush)
        painter.drawRect(self.boundingRect())

    def setStyle(self, style):
        pen = self.pen()
        pen.setStyle(style)
        self.setPen(pen)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(-400, -400, 800, 800)
    w = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(scene)
    scene.addItem(Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 100))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```